# localhost SSL not working in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, wamp, wampserver

I am developing a website locally using wamp.  The site uses ssl and works completely fine in firefox.  In Google Chrome, I get an error:

`https://example.local/` gives me this error

```
This webpage is not available

The connection to example.local was interrupted.

Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Check your Internet connection. Restart any router, modem, or other network devices you     may be using.
Add Google Chrome as a permitted program in your firewall's or antivirus software's     settings. If it is already a permitted program, try deleting it from the list of permitted programs and adding it again.
If you use a proxy server, check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server, adjust your proxy settings: Go to the wrench menu > Options > Under the Hood > Change proxy settings... > LAN Settings and deselect the "Use a proxy server for your LAN" checkbox.

Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

`http://example.local/` works fine in chrome.

I should note that in IE I get `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage` error, but again, it works fine in firefox...

Any help?

Comment: Have you checked in your firewall settings (perhaps "advanced" options) allow connections to be made from other applications? (It's possible that Firefox is allowed to connect the example.local:443, but not the other.)

Comment: The windows firewall is turned off.

Comment: My flag was disputed, but I still believe that you might find better support for this on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ as it's technically not programming related.

Comment: I see, would webmasters or serverfault be more appropriate?